# Will peanut seeds grow if they are missing their papers and/or split in half?

Tags: seeds, peanuts

I have some peanut seeds, and about half of them have lost their papers and/or are split in half. Will these grow properly, or should I remove them? I don't have any experience with these.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Missing paper is no problem, some of the broken in half seeds could grow, if the embryo is intact on one of the halfs, but it would only have half as much energy to start with.